# Django and Mysql 8: 2012, 'Error in server handshake'

Tags: mysql, django, handshake

I am trying to install Django on new developer machine running MacOS High Sierra with latest version of Mysql (Ver 8.0.11). When I try to: python manage.py runserver i get this error message:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2012, 'Error in server handshake')
```

Does anyone has any experience with this?

I have installed and I am running virtual environment that I have created with python3.6. I have installed mysqlclient too but I can't find anyone with this issue..

Comment: If you have both `MySQLdb` and `mysqlclient` installed in the virtualenv, remove both, then install just the newest `mysqlclient`.

Comment: Also, based on this Percona article, it seems MySQL 8 has changed authentication plugin defaults. https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/01/24/mysql-8-0-4-rc-beware-auth_socket-users/

Comment: I havent installed MySQLdb. I read that it is not required to install if I install mysqlclient. I havte tried to install and uninstall mysqlclient several times without luck. Do you recommend me to install MySQLdb and how to do that?

Comment: No, `mysqlclient` is superior to `MySQLdb`.